# Traps in the World of Darkness

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, chronicles-of-darkness-2e

I intend to place my characters in a trapped "dungeon" (I'm stealing the concept from the movie [Cube](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123755/) as a God Machine experiment, and [team building exercise](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/42164/1015)), however I am unable to locate rules for traps (at least they aren't explicitly mentioned in the Index of WoD, Armory, or Armory Reloaded). What kinds of rules/rolls would apply? Finding traps? trap doors? disabling? dealing with "surprise attacks from the environment"? etc.

Comment: Hey xenoterracide, since you have been asking alot of questions about nWoD/nwod-god-machine I would appreciate your input in this Meta about tagging nWoD. http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4773/lets-get-a-clear-consensus-on-the-use-of-nwod-vs-nwod-god-machine
I want you to understand, that while I use many of your questions as examples, this is not an attack on you, just want to get more consensus
(Thanks  Wesley Obenshain for fixing my link)

Comment: Who downvoted the question? I don't know that makes it different from other rule locations questions common on this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could all wish hard copies came with a search feature. Or that DriveThruRPGs Print-on-Demand service handled full bleed.

The rules for traps start on **page 184** of the original **Armory** book, under the **Traps** heading of the section entitled **Security Systems and Traps** in **Chapter Five: Equipment and Accessories**. However, those rules may require some adaptation to make them fully compatible with God Machine rules, including but not limited to the use of Conditions. (Thanks, Oxinabox).