# "Slow" traps in the world of darkness

Tags: house-rules, chronicles-of-darkness-1e

This is a follow up to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44544/1015) after reading the rules I realized they don't quite fit all of my use cases, so being a novice GM, I'm hoping the community can help me come up with some advanced rules.

As a reiteration of what I'm doing, I'm stealing the concept from the movie [Cube](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123755/) as a God Machine experiment, and [team building exercise](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/42164/1015).

What if the trap is "slow", take the scene from resident evil with the laser room, the laser moves from end of the room to another, it's completely dodge-able (until it turns into a grid), but the rules only allow for traps with instant damage. That laser is excessively slow but I basically see characters being able to attempt to dodge some traps.

I'm trying to determine what rolls the players should have to make. whether they should be contested, is it possible for them to partially succeed in avoiding a trap? etc. (e.g. a lethal trap that the character dodges but not completely resulting in a 1 lethal maybe) (note: this is house rules territory)

Comment: So your question is "how do I mechanically render a slow-moving, avoidable trap in this game?"

Comment: I guess, yes, trying to determine what rolls the characters should have to make, whether they should be contested, etc. @Zachiel updated

Answer (score 1):

What about making the player make X dodge rolls, as if he was attacked X times? If the player is forced to jump in several directions, maybe you can add a pair of rolls to see if he is disoriented, which would require more dodge rolls.

Comment: IIRC (but I don't have my books with me atm) dodges are contested, so what's the right way to stat the traps? They aren't people, and theoretically they'd have some scale of difficulty to avoid...

Comment: You could make dodge-equivalent rolls against a threshold, but I would warn against multiple rolls against the same hazard. In my experience players hate them, and they cheapen the drama of each roll. Rolling for a scene is far better option IMO.

Comment: In base now (unlike in God Machine) dodge isn't contented. It isn't even rolled. Dodge means doubling the penalty from Defense to that attackers to hit roll.
However i think Flammas use of the lowercase dodge, is as Dave gets at, meaning roll to dodge, which would be either a Wits+Dex, or a Dex+Athletics, depending if noticing is the hard part or avoiding is the hard part

Comment: maybe, because obviously this thing rather discusses that there's no "to hit roll" hits are an automatic success which is part of the problem.

Comment: I would almost see it as an extended skill test but with a limited time frame